# Two versions of python giving two different results for the same code

Tags: python, skyfield

The following code produces two different results if run using Python2 or Python3.  Why?

```
from skyfield.api import wgs84, load

latitude =  -35
longitude =  150
altitude =  100
year = 2022
month = 1
day = 21
hour = 14
minute = 6
seconds = 43.941372

ts = load.timescale()
t_meas = ts.utc(year,month,day,hour,minute,seconds)

radar = wgs84.latlon(latitude, longitude, altitude)
radar_ECI = radar.at(t_meas)
print(radar_ECI.position.m)
```

Output with skyfield 1.41
[-2804378.01051857  4419981.90545062 -3632070.86144542]

Output with skyfield 1.40
[-2804356.81834716  4419995.31425895 -3632070.90655877]

Comment: Well, the short answer is that Python 3 is not backwards-compatible with Python 2, and does not claim to be. More specifically, there may be a bug in Skyfield that does not correctly account for the differences.(Also Python 2 hasn't been officially supported in years.) What outputs are you getting?

Comment: Do you have the same version of skyfield in both Python environments?

Comment: I have discovered that, in fact, the two versions of Skyfield were not the same.  Version 1.40 was installed on Python2 and 1.41 on Python3.  Once I upgraded to 1.41, the problem was solved.

Comment: @Jonathan Awesome! Would you please post that as an answer? You can even accept it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The two versions of Skyfield were not the same. Version 1.40 was installed on Python2 and 1.41 on Python3. Once I upgraded to 1.41, the problem was solved.  However, nothing in the change-log for Skyfield seems to explain why it would produce different results between these two versions.

Comment: It could be as simple as the new version using something like `from __future__ import division`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest updating your question to show the two outputs that you were getting. Without them, readers can't tell whether you are asking about a very big different in output or a very small one.

One possible answer (but without seeing the outputs, I don't know if the difference between them is of a reasonable size to match this explanation): most Skyfield releases — ideally, all Skyfield releases, but sometimes I forget — carry a fresh download of the most recent and up-to-date ∆T table from the IERS. They are constantly predicting, then measuring, the orientation of the Earth. Between Skyfield 1.40 and 1.41 the table was updated, which could mean very slightly different estimates of where the Earth is pointing over the past few months. Typically it would mean a difference east-west, but no difference in the returned position in a north-south direction.

Comment: That's an extremely reasonable explanation for what I'm seeing, as the differences are very small.

Answer (score -2):

Undoubtedly, there are many differences in how Python 2 and 3 are coded, and it should be considered. But if you want to work with Python 3 with the same Python 2 coding, you can use this **future** built in library.
It may be different in giving the amount

```
syntax : from __future__ import ..
```

You can read about it in the official Python Document:

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#the-short-explanation

Maybe this article will help you too, To better understand the differences:

[https://cv-tricks.com/how-to/developer-guide-to-key-differences-between-python-2-and-3/#:~:text=Python%203%20uses%20unicode%20strings,using%20the%20bytes()%20function.&text=Python%202%20provides%20useful%20functional,default%20in%20the%20global%20namespace](https://cv-tricks.com/how-to/developer-guide-to-key-differences-between-python-2-and-3/#:%7E:text=Python%203%20uses%20unicode%20strings,using%20the%20bytes()%20function.&text=Python%202%20provides%20useful%20functional,default%20in%20the%20global%20namespace).

Comment: While this is generally useful information, it appears that the difference here is not in the asker's code, but in the library they're using (potentially even different versions of the library).

Comment: I wrote this information only for better understanding and more information and if the questioner is informed about the performance of this library in both versions of Python.